# Class and variable

Tags: java, class, variables

I'm triying to create a game on java. The game is working and now I would like to create a class with the high score. The variable "score" already exists in one class, and I created a variable highscore in a another one.

In the second class I wrote :

```
if (highscore < score) {
highscore = score;}
```

But it doesn't recognize the variable "score" even if all the class are in the same package and the variables and the class are public... Does somebody can help me?

Comment: Well they're in different classes, as you said. You'd need to refer to an instance of the class containing score. For example: `if (highscore < player.score)` - although I wouldn't recommend using non-private fields anyway...

Comment: What if there will be many instances of class with different `score`s? Which one of them should `score` in `if (highscore < score)` represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Score is an attribute of an other class, so try  to access to your object from  this class then access to it.
Example:

```
Player p = new Player();
...
if(highscore < p.score)
...
```

Comment: It is possible to create an object in a class which is not a "main class"? The class with the variable "score" is not a main class...

Comment: Yes of course, JAVA is an Object Oriented language. You can create as many object as you need in each classes methods (respecting OO rules and visibilities). Moreover, it's recommended to avoid doing all your logic in the "main" class or main method. I suggest to learn about object oriented programming paradigm best practices.

Answer (score 0):

If your score is not a field of an object you could write it like so:

```
class Score{
 private int score=5;
 public static int getScore(){
  return score;
 }
}

class yourClass{
if(highscore<Score.getScore())
 highscore=Score.getScore();

}
```